# Chamando função Javascript do pai de dentro de uma iframe filha que não está na mesma pasta que o pai

Tags: javascript, iframe

tenho o seguinte cenário:

Um arquivo pai está chamando uma iframe filha.
o pai e a filha estão em pastas completamente separadas.

Preciso que a filha chame em javascript uma função, também em javascript, que está no pai. Como estão em pastas distintas o código `parent.funcao();` não funciona, correto? Como eu faço para substituir esse `parent` pelo caminho do servidor onde o pai está?

Exemplo:

pagina.htm (Pai)

```
<style>
*{
margin:0;padding:0;
}
#iframe{
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<script>
function WHFRAME(w,h){
var FrameWH = document.getElementById("iframe");

FrameWH.style.width  = w+"px";
FrameWH.style.height = h+"px";
}
</script>

<iframe src="iframe.htm" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

iframe.htm (filha)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>pagina</title>
<style>
*{
margin:0;padding:0;
}
html,body{
overflow:hidden;
}
#corpo{
width:990px;
height:auto;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ResizeWH(){
var w;
var h;

w = document.getElementById("corpo").clientWidth;
h = document.getElementById("corpo").clientHeight;
window.parent.WHFRAME(w,h);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="corpo">
<p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p>
<p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p>
<p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p>
<p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p>
<p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p>
<p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p>
<p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p>
<p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p>
</div>
</body>
<script>
ResizeWH();
</script>
</html>
```

No exemplo acima os dois arquivos estão na mesma pasta, logo ele funciona, no meu cenário a filha está em outra pasta (mesmo servidor, porém em unidades diferentes). Sendo assim, a linha `<iframe src="iframe.htm" id="iframe"></iframe>` seria assim `<iframe src="http://caminho.../iframe.htm" id="iframe"></iframe>`.

Obs.: É um script para deixar o tamanho da iframe filha dinamico dentro do pai.

Comment: Inclua o seu código como um exemplo verificável para que o problema possa ser reproduzido.

Comment: Não importa em que pasta está, o iframe sempre será o filho. Só precisa estar no mesmo domínio.

Comment: E se não estiver no mesmo domínio? Como poderia ser feito?

Comment: @ZacariasJunior se não estiver no mesmo domínio não é possível.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma: como o arquivo pai não estava no mesmo domínio da iframe filha, criei um arquivo no mesmo domínio que 
o pai redirecionando para a filha que está em outro domínio e chamei ele no arquivo pai. Ficando 3 arquivos da seguinte forma:

pagina.htm (Pai)

```
<style>
*{
margin:0;padding:0;
}
#iframe{
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<script>
function WHFRAME(w,h){
var FrameWH = document.getElementById("iframe");

FrameWH.style.width  = w+"px";
FrameWH.style.height = h+"px";
}
</script>

<iframe src="redirect.php" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Redirect.php

```
<?php

include "caminho.../iframe.htm";

?>
```

iframe.htm (Filha)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>pagina</title>
<style>
*{
margin:0;padding:0;
}
html,body{
overflow:hidden;
}
#corpo{
width:990px;
height:auto;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ResizeWH(){
var w;
var h;

w = document.getElementById("corpo").clientWidth;
h = document.getElementById("corpo").clientHeight;
window.parent.WHFRAME(w,h);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="corpo">
<p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p>
<p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p>
<p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p> <p>Conteudo</p>

</div>
</body>
<script>
ResizeWH();
</script>
</html>
```